# I haven't used compile anywhere still getting "Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'"

Tags: android, gradle

I haven't used compile anywhere either in App or Project level build.gradle file. But still I am getting this error.

I went through other questions related to this on stackoverflow but most solutions suggested to replace compile with api or implementation, But since I didn't use it anywhere I can't find a fix. Please help.

App Level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.smartseller"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
}
```

Project Level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Warning Code I got

```
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app
```

I am using android studio version 3.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating `com.google.gms:google-services` from `3.0.0` to `3.2.0` or any other latest version.

Comment: Thanks for solution, actually I change it to 4.2.0 as suggested by IDE. It got fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you help me with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56659788/nesting-of-firebase-onclick-listener-not-working

Answer (score 2):

Change this in your App Level build.gradle
might be issue with this dependency

**Replace this**

```
     implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
```

**With this**

```
 implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
```

**-:For Android 14+ support, downgrade zxing:core to 3.3.0 or earlier:-**

```
  implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') { transitive = false }
  implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
```

Reference [Link](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded)

Happy Learning ...

Comment: Any explanation for this?? how will this solve the issue?

Comment: sometime dependency required  latest version.
reason : team working on the issues and they updated there dependencies as per the issues so we need to update it .

Comment: @Arbaz.in Changed it but no difference in warning.