# Nesting of firebase Onclick Listener not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app and a part of it is to submit a device id to firebase and if that device id  is submitted it will upload a dummy class device status which is later to be changed and used by NodeMCU. 
But the problem is that when I create one database reference and put the device id on firebase and within it if I try to put another addOnCompleteListener for pushing dummy device status class, I get some errors.

My function to submit code and a dummy device status object when the code is submitted.

```
    void submitCode(String scannedCode){
        code=scannedCode;
        databaseReference.setValue(code).addOnCompleteListener(
                this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            DeviceStatus deviceStatus = new DeviceStatus();
                            deviceStatus.deviceID = code;
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DeviceStatus").child(code).setValue(deviceStatus).addOnCompleteListener(
                                    this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> subTask) {
                                            if (subTask.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Product ID Successfully Entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                finish();
                                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), switchStatus.class));
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            );

                        }
                    }
                }
        );


    }
```

Here databaseReference is a global variable as:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
```

And initialised as

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DeviceStatus").child(devideID);
```

Android Studio Editor warning says:

```
Cannot resolve method 'addOnCompleteListener(anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<java.lang.Void>, anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<java.lang.Void>)'
```

Build error says

```
error: no suitable method found for addOnCompleteListener(<anonymous OnCompleteListener<Void>>,<anonymous OnCompleteListener<Void>>)
method Task.addOnCompleteListener(Executor,OnCompleteListener<Void>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnCompleteListener<Void>> cannot be converted to Executor)
method Task.addOnCompleteListener(Activity,OnCompleteListener<Void>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnCompleteListener<Void>> cannot be converted to Activity)
```

Updated function:

```
    void submitCode(String scannedCode){
        code=scannedCode;
        databaseReference.setValue(code).addOnCompleteListener(
                this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
//                            sendSwitchStatus(code);
                            DeviceStatus deviceStatus = new DeviceStatus();
                            deviceStatus.deviceID = code;
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DeviceStatus").child(code).setValue(deviceStatus).addOnCompleteListener( getBaseContext(), new OnCompleteListener<Void>(){


                                public void onComplete(@Nullable Task<void> subTask){
                                    if (subTask.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Product ID Successfully Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        finish();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), switchStatus.class));
                                    }
                                }


                            });

                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Comment: What's the data type of `databaseReference`?

Comment: @Astha its of type DatabaseReference, I have updated details in the question.

Comment: Try updating `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DeviceStatus").child(code).setValue(deviceStatus).addOnCompleteListener(
                                    this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>()` with `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DeviceStatus").child(code).setValue(deviceStatus).addOnCompleteListener(
                                    mContext, new OnCompleteListener<Void>()` (Use context or reference of your Activity)

Comment: what's mContext here??

Comment: In my case, I have used the reference of my `BaseActivity` inside inner `addOnCompleteListener`

Comment: To correct myself, use reference of `Activity`instead of `this` in inner listener (not Context, addOnCompleteListener requires first Parameter as `Activity`)

Comment: @Astha Now I got another error on inner onComplete function::::::::::------ 'onComplete(Task<void>)' in 'Anonymous class derived from com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener' clashes with 'onComplete(Task<TResult>)' in 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Comment: Sorry for leave a wrong answer down below,Can you update your codes?

Comment: Can you please show the updated code now?

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: Can you show us required Firebase database structure setch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use activity context while setting `addOnCompleteListener` second time.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int toggle = 0;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Activity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        activity = this;
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DeviceStatus").child("");
    }
    void submitCode(String scannedCode){
        String code = scannedCode;
        databaseReference.setValue(code).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DeviceStatus").child("").setValue("").addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Since there was some confusion regarding `Activity`'s reference, I have wriiten some Sample code similar as yours(some variables are replaced with "" just for sample). Please check and feel free to ask any further on this.

Comment: What's getApplicationContext().ge??

Comment: Oops!I was trying something else.. Have updated the code